# Xamarin Forms Listview disable cell highlight

Tags: xamarin.forms

This seems like a really primitive problem and should be solved with a property changed. But here's my issue:

- User selects a cell from a listview.
- I override the background color for the cell, and set it to the appropriate color (we have different color themes).
- When I go back to my listview, and select the same item again, the cell runs through the same code as it did before, but the highlighted color is default.

One of the only ways around this that I've seen is `NOT` setting the `SelectedItem` to null. Which I do because if I don't, and I go back to my listview, I can't select the same item.

You'd think that Xamarin has a property on the listview `HighlightCellSelection` and I can just set it to false. Anywho, any way around this?

Here's my code:

```
ListView.ItemSelected += (s, e) =>
                {
                    ((ListView)s).BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
                    XamarinMobile.ViewModels.GridCellViewModel cell = (XamarinMobile.ViewModels.GridCellViewModel)e.SelectedItem;
                    ((ListView)s).SelectedItem = null;
                }
```

Also in my binding context, which does the same thing:

```
    this.Tapped += (s, e) => {
        this.View.BackgroundColor = App.IsDarkThemeEnabled() ? Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black : Xamarin.Forms.Color.White;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what was happening was that the property didn't get set if I set it to the same as I did before. It was fixed by simply changing it to `transparent` first and then the desired color.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is on iOS, but if I understood your question correctly and all you want to do is disable default Cell highlighting, you can make a ViewCellRenderer and change the cell selection style.

```
public class ViewCellRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewCellRenderer
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
        cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear; 
        return cell;
    }
}
```